# Get a frame count of a MP4 file

Tags: video, mp4, codec

I made my own MP4 parser (it recursively parses an atom tree and the content of some atoms).

I already see the duration of a video (in seconds) and I know how to find a start of a frame at a specific time (in seconds). However, I don't know how to find a number of frames (and compute the FPS) without decoding actual frames.

I was using the `moov - trak - 0 - mdia - minf - stbl - stsz` array, which usually has one value per frame. But now, I found a MP4 video, which has 370 values in "stsz" (370 video samples), but only 184 frames.

Comment: **(1)** How are you confirming it's only 184 frames? Also **184** x2 would be **368**, so I wonder if it's because your video is interlaced (just a thought, never checked if MP4 has doubled frame numbers when interlaced)? **(2)** Is there an EDTS (edit list) affecting how many frames are played by decoder? **(3)** Is there a CTTS (optional) to check the summed total of frames?

Comment: This is the video: https://www.photopea.com/ateez%20interview%20cut.mp4 . It does have "ctts"!

Comment: @VC.One I looked into "CTTS" and it has 324 items. Could you look at my video and tell me how many frames does it have?

Comment: There is 324 items because some time entries are used by multiple frames (usually 2 in your file). They do account for 370 frames when summed up.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding...

> *"...How to **find the number of frames** (and thus **compute the FPS**) without decoding actual frames?"* 
> *"I found a MP4 video, which has 370 values in `"stsz"` (370 video samples), but only 184 frames."*

**Edit:** (regarding comments)

The file is not corrupt. It is `6.195` seconds if you follow the actual duration (370 frames) of the contained video data. It is `2.820` seconds if you follow the edit list's duration, which is edited to play around 3 seconds from total of 6 secs (or play 169 frames from total 370).

Tested MP4 files in Chrome browser (which itself follows the edit-list settings)...

- This [ateez_full_elst.mp4](https://vc-lut.000webhostapp.com/demos/public/ateez_full_elst.mp4) has full 6 second duration. Achieved by editing the `elst` atom via hex editor. Making one segment entry with a `start` of 0, with a segment `duration` time of 6 seconds. Edit global `mvhd` duration also to match your preferred MP4 duration.
- This [ateez_elst.mp4](https://vc-lut.000webhostapp.com/demos/public/ateez_elst.mp4) is your file re-saved as MP4 using FFmpeg (with `-codec copy` options).
  FFmpeg seems to strictly follow the edit list and so it outputs a 3 second file.

**short version:**

```
FPS = ( stsz_sampleCount / (mdhd_duration / mdhd_timescale) );
```

**details**: 
Your MP4 seems to have gone through some video trimmer/editor that modified the bytes.

- The original duration is **6.195 seconds**, equates into **370 samples** of the `stsz` atom.
- The **edited duration**, based on the edits in the `elst` atom, is now **2.820 seconds**.

I did not check bytes to manually count frames, so I cannot confirm if there is really 370 samples in `mdat` or if such metadata details were kept unchanged for the sake of future decoders. This means, for example because of how the **FPS** is calculated using that **370** number, it would be incorrect if the sample count was lower.

*FPS calculation for your MP4 file:*

- From **mdhd** atom get the values of: `timescale` (=15360) and `duration` (=95154).
- Calculate: `playTime` = ( `duration` / `timescale` ) =  6.195 secs (*ie:* Math.ceil from 6.194927...).
- From **stsz** atom, get the `sampleCount` (=370).

then:

- `fps` = (`sampleCount` / `playtime`) = 60 FPS (*ie:* Math.ceil from 59.725...).
- `frameCount` = `sampleCount` = ( `fps` * `playTime`) = 370 total Frames.

**accounting for elst:** 
You must read the `elst` (under `edts` atom) to find out how much of that frame count is "edited" (can be duration trimmed, can be longer frame duration, can be segment time-skipping, etc). The edits affect the overall duration (except if just doing reverse playback).

You can see your `elst` has only **1 entry** (the one segment that will be played) and it says the segment is extracted from time **1.972 seconds** and has a duration of **2.820 seconds**.

It is the only segment played: 
 So the `actual_playTime` duration is **3 seconds** (*ie:* Math.ceil from 2.8 seconds).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Why should I use "duration" and "timescale" from "mdhd" and not from "mvhd"? They are often different. Also, are you able to extract more than 184 frames out of my video? Can I find this number 184 somehow?

Comment: Because you specifically need the timescale and duration of the video track itself for video FPS (not the global `mvhd` value). I don't know how you are getting 184 frames. There are 170 frames for the shown 2.820 seconds duration. Changing the `elst` did not change duration, so I think there really is 3 seconds worth of frames in `mdat` but the metadata has listings for 370 frames.

Comment: PS: No worries I'm glad to help. Your JS code for making Cubic Splines was useful to my Photoshop ACV curves file processing at one time.

Comment: Go to www.Photopea.com , press File - Open, and load that MP4 file. Drag the "FPS" slider to the right and press "OK". You will see 184 different frames extracted on the right side. So there are more than 170 frames in the file.

Comment: Shouldn't I simply consider this MP4 as corrupted, and ignore any problems happening around it? Are there often MP4 files like this one?

Comment: The file is not corrupt. Your app will have to decide if it extracts frames according to the known total in `stsz`, or according to the `elst` edit list... For example an edit might make frame 1 stay on screen for 5 seconds, now if a user has the slider set to 1 frame per sec do they get 5 unique `stsz` frames for each second or they see frame 1 repeated 5 times? Maybe, if you detect an edit list, just offer a notice for user to choose "all frames" or "only played frames"...

Comment: PS: When I open your MP4 file in Photopea with Chrome browser, I get only 90 frames (range 0-89) after maxing slider to the right. Not sure how you're getting 184 from same file. Really it should be 169 frames if reading by edit-list, or 370 frames if reading by all available frames. You'll have to investigate what goes on. Remember `ctts` plays a part in the frame's display time-point.

Comment: I really can get 184 different frames out of the file. How many frames can you get using whatever-you-want-tool? There must be a way to tell how many frames an MP4 file has :D